# "He was nether unsatisfactory nor, exceeded the expectations."

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, neither-nor

Is there anything wrong in this sentence?

"He was nether unsatisfactory nor, exceeded the expectations."

I was trying to say.
He is not very good

or

also , he is not very bad

He is neutral.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! Please see "How do I ask about checking my text?" in the [help pages](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). We don't do simple proof-reading: we can help with specific points of difficulty. If you are learning English then [ell.se] may help, but **they don't do proof-reading either**.

Comment: Are you looking for a word to mean that?

Comment: yes, i would like to

Comment: Then would *mediocre* work?

Comment: ok...........................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Nether" means "lower" as in the nether regions (regions below the surface of the Earth). I believe you meant "neither".

The sentence should be: "He was neither unsatisfactory, nor exceeded expectations."

Comment: This answer is almost correct, but I think it should really read: *He was neither unsatisfactory, nor **did he exceed** expectations.*